# Javascript to track if a click opened a new tab/window

Tags: javascript

In my application when a user is clicking any "a href" link then a "loading" dialog appears (this is necessary for many reasons beyond the scope of this question). Some users, however, open some links in new tabs/windows, thus the "loading" dialog should not be shown in the opener window. Is that possible to track somehow with js?

Comment: you could track the click to the link by binding to the onclick event and then check the event whether or not the user clicked with the right or left mouse button to deduce whether or not to show the dialog

Comment: Well, some people right-click and chose an option from the popupmenu to open a link in a new tab. This ends up in a normal click :(

Comment: I wish you put the JS code part that handle click event, maybe we can got idea for modification to find solution, anyway, you need to handle middle button click as well :D , my idea to return false when anybody right-click on link so you prevent him doing that, and hold middle click like that or find a way to show dialog.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar i'd be pissed if a website prevented right clicking.

Comment: @dqhendricks me too, but I didn't mean on all website, I meant only on links, anyway you can use noScript add-on to pass that :P

Comment: @Al-Mothafar I meant on links. This is typically the only thing I use right click on in a website. I like to be able to choose whether to open in the current page, or in a new window. If the developer prevented this, and I could only open in the current window, I would be upset. It's a bad move from a usability standpoint imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$( 'a' ).click( function( e ) {
   if ( e.which === 1 ) {
      showLoadingDialog();
   }
} );
```

Only shows loading dialog if left mouse button is clicked.

Comment: he said he is already has that, he has a code to handle left clicking and show dialog, he just want to handle right-click then New Tab method to show dialog.

Comment: The approach you suggested is correct, I have reversed the logic i.e. show loading message only when the left mouse button is clicked and do not show the message in all other cases.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar this is not quite what he had. He was showing the loading image in all cases. The code above allows him to only show the loading image in the case of a left click (and not the right/other click).